# Java Prepared Statement with IS NULL

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

Let say I have a MySQL table like this:

VARCHAR 100 | VARCHAR 100 | VARCHAR 100

[ ID ] [ NAME ] [ NICKNAME ] [ FAVORITE_COLOR ]

1 John Johnny RED

2 Eric NULL GREEN

**I want to select the 2nd row where Nickname is NULL using the following prepared statement in Java:**

```
statement = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name = ? AND nickname = ?"

prepared = connection.prepareStatement(statement)
prepared.setString(1, "Eric")
prepared.setString(2, null)

result = prepared.executeQuery()
```

This query does not work.  The result set is empty.

Another option I tried is:

```
statement.setNull(2,java.sql.Types.VARCHAR)
```

This also does not work and the result set is empty.

Lastly, I tried a different SQL but its clearly wrong and returns too many rows (because it's not strict enough):

```
statement = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name = ? AND (nickname IS NULL) OR (nickname = ?)"
```

This selects too many rows in my case.

**So my question is:  How, using a Java PreparedStatement, can I select a row using the MySQL 'IS NULL'?**

Comment: Put parentheses around your `or` condition: `WHERE name = ? AND (nickname IS NULL OR nickname = ?)`

Comment: I believe `setNull` only works for insert/update queries. `name = null` is not valid in SQL, so you must manage that yourself (because SQL force you to)

Comment: @JBNizet yes that was the answer in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a well known limit of SQL databases. For most databases, you must write `... WHERE field IS NULL` to test for NULL values of `field`. Neither `... field = NULL`, nor `... field = :param` where `:param` is a parameter of a parameterized query ever match a NULL value.

So the only solution is to explicitly write `field IS NULL` in your query.
Said differently, you need 2 different queries, one for non-null values (and only one parameter) and the other one for null values (and 2 parameter).

```
statement = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name = ? AND nickname = ?";
statement = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name = ? AND nickname IS NULL";
```

You can use the trick (beware of parentheses as explained by JBNizet)

```
statement = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name = ? AND (nickname = ? OR nickname IS NULL)";
```

If you want to still use 2 parameters for the query asking for NULL values.

Comment: Or you can use the null-safe operator `<=>`.

Comment: This did the trick.  Both solutions worked in my case.  What I found interesting was your attention to the parentheses.  I had messed up one of my queries as seen in the question above which used the (nickname = ?) OR (nickname IS NULL) ... instead of (nickname = ? OR nickname IS NULL)

Answer (score 3):

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to
>
> NULL-safe equal. This operator performs an equality comparison like the = operator, but returns 1 rather than NULL if both operands are NULL, and 0 rather than NULL if one operand is NULL.
>
> The <=> operator is equivalent to the standard SQL IS NOT DISTINCT FROM operator.

For null to work update your query to:
`statement = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name = ? AND nickname <=> ?"`

Answer (score 0):

@John Anderson, you validated an answer which actually **doesn't work**.
Let me explain.

Let's take back the validated comparison and focus on the second WHERE clause:

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE
  name = ?
  AND (nickname = ? OR nickname IS NULL)
```

In the case `? = 'something'`, you have:

```sql
AND (nickname = 'something' OR nickname IS NULL)

-- which is equivalent to:
AND (NULL OR nickname IS NULL)

-- which is equivalent to:
AND (nickname IS NULL)
```

So **you always get the line with NULLs as nickname, whatever the `?` value is** (side effect when `?` is actually not NULL).
Actually, you always get the NULL lines AND the ones you are looking for in the case `?` is not NULL.

**Below is one way to actually do the trick (tested personally):**

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE
  name = ?
  AND ((? IS NULL AND nickname IS NULL) OR (? IS NOT NULL AND nickname = ?))
```

Details of the 2 main cases:

1. `?` is `NULL`:

```sql
AND ((NULL IS NULL AND nickname IS NULL) OR (NULL IS NOT NULL AND nickname = ?))

-- which is equivalent to:
AND ((TRUE AND nickname IS NULL) OR (FALSE AND nickname = NULL))

-- which is equivalent to:
AND ((nickname IS NULL) OR (FALSE AND NULL))

-- which is equivalent to:
AND ((nickname IS NULL) OR (FALSE))

-- which is equivalent to:
AND (nickname IS NULL)
```

So you exactly get lines where the nickname is NULL.

2. `?` = `'something'`:

```sql
AND (('something' IS NULL AND nickname IS NULL) OR ('something' IS NOT NULL AND nickname = 'something'))

-- which is equivalent to:
AND ((FALSE AND nickname IS NULL) OR (TRUE AND nickname = 'something'))

-- which is equivalent to:
AND (FALSE OR (nickname = 'something'))

-- which is equivalent to:
AND (nickname = 'something')
```

So you exactly get lines where the nickname = 'something'.